# How to run an executable file in Xcode from another app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 2 apps that I want to incorporate in 1 app. I want to have the executables available inside the Xcode project when I press the button the app from one of the executables start to run. Is this possible? Ive seen this done with apps such as f.lux https://github.com/jefferyleo/f.lux

Answer (score 0):

`Build Settings -> Add new Copy Files phase`

There you can include other binaries/apps to be copied to your application bundles content folder.

Then you can refer to and open the URL of the included binary:

```
let appUrl = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Contents/Path/To/YourApp")
NSWorkspace.shared().open(appUrl)
```

Comment: Is it under packaging? Whats the name of the Copy Files Phase

Comment: And how would I do this on iOS? Its not for the appstore

Comment: Sorry, not possible on iOS. Thought you meant macOS.